# Can I use a ternary relationship as an associative entity?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I want to know whether I can connect a ternary relationship to a another entity without that forming an n-ary relationship. To describe in terms of tables, I want to get a reference in the ternary relationship table to another (entity's) table.

Comment: What information modeling method/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually and generally, yes.

It can reasonably be called a binary relationship between the other and the associative entity, and a 4-way relationship among/over the other and the entities that form the associative entity.

But what *exactly* your terms mean and how you are allowed to design depends on your particular information modeling method and/or tool.

Eg your method/tool might or might not require that you add an identifier to an association type and use that in other tables rather than just the 3 columns.

Eg E-R Modeling distinguishes between "entity" and "relationship" types (each type having a corresponding table with other columns for "properties"). But this isn't actually necessary in informaton modeling since an "entity" could just be considered a 1-ary "association" and a "property" could just be considered an "entity". (Is a "marriage" a "relationship" between spouses and/or an "entity" with an anniversary and/or "property" of a family or wedding?) Also, *any* columns that are unique in *any table or query result* identify *some* "thing" type whether or not it is one of the base (non-associative or associative) "entity" types.

(More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27272088/3404097).)