# Normalization for music/concerts database

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, primary-key, one-to-many, database-normalization

My understanding with normalization after reading my book and going through a few youtube tutorials is that one of the important things is to not have repeating values. More specifically the primary key (ID) should not repeat.

So if I am working with some Tables in a Music/Concert database, then the following would be bad:

```
**CREATE TABLE Artists**                                                     

ArtistID INT *PRIMARY KEY*
ArtistName  VARCHAR(30)                        
Albums
```

- ^Having Albums in the Artists table would be bad as there is One
  Artist for Many Albums. Therefore the ArtistID would have to show up
  in multiple rows [once for each album by the artist]

**Question:** Should a table like this have a foreign key that ties to another Table? The related table I would think about is obviously Albums.

Albums would have columns like:

```
CREATE Table Albums (
       Album_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       Album_Name VARCHAR(30), 
       Artist VARCHAR(30),
       Release_Date DATETIME,
       Genre or GenreID,
       Primary Key (Album_ID) );
```

**Question:** But albums have songs. However I can't have Album ID as the Primary Key and then have all the songs with the repeating Primary Key of Album ID for each can I? Should I therefore keep the attribute 'Songs' out of the Album table?

Comment: Q1(A1): But couldn't multiple artists be on a single album? So don't you need an AlbumArtists table to resolve the Many to many between Artist and album? Q2(A2) yes songs belong in it's own table to be at least 3rd normal form compliant.

Comment: I suppose I have a confusion on when its better to use many-to-many vs one-to-many and vice versa? What would be in the AlbumArtists?

Comment: You should seldom(never?) allow a many-to-many to persist.  It should always be one to one, or one to many. or many to one.  AlbumArtists would have the ID's from both Album and artist.  and maybe release dates (some albums are-refactored and re-released right?  so a release date might go there along with the publisher (sometimes different publishers) etc.  Why you don't want many to many is because without the junction/associative table you can't support the many-to-many as you would need multiple ID's in each base table.

Comment: Albums like "The best of the 80's" is a good example where an album could ahve multiple artists since each song is likely from a different group.  This is a prime example of why you would need to have an ArtistAlbum and even perhaps "AlbumArtistSong" table.

Comment: You do not seem to have grasped what is going on. You need to memorize and apply definitions. A PK is just some CK that you decided to call that. A CK is a set of columns that *is* unique and doesn't contain a smaller such set. There's no way a PK column *could* repeat values, so what do you mean, "should not"? Also, there aren't tables "for" entities, there are just tables for *application/business relationships*. (Although ER modeling used tables in a restricted way that does associate "entity" tables with "entity types".)

Comment: Why are you asking all this instead of just *normalizing*, like you were told? You seem to have mistaken the explanations of the motivations for and intuitions behind normalization for the actual procedure you are supposed to follow. You also don't seem to understand the basic idea of a relation/table representing a particular relevant application/business relationship. FKs just give *some info* about these, but to use the database & determine FKs you need to know *what each table's application/business relationship is*, ie *what rows go in each table in an application/business situation*.

Comment: Re design fundamentals see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41081728/3404097) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42193358/3404097).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Question: Should a table like this have a foreign key that ties to another Table? The related table I would think about is obviously Albums.*

If the relationship between artist and album is one to many... (if the rules are that an "artist" can have zero, one or more "albums", and an "album" belongs to exactly one "artist")

We would implement that relationship by storing `artist_id` as a foreign key column on the `album` table.

Something like this:

artists:

```
artist
------
id           'PK'
name varchar
```

albums:

```
album
-----
id           'PK'
artist_id    'FK ref artist.id'
title
year
artwork
```

By storing a value in the `artist_id` column of `album`, that is a reference to a row in the `artist` table.

artist:

```
 id    name
 ----  --------
    1  Kansas
    2  Styx
```

album:

```
 id    artist_id  name                  year
 ----  ---------  --------------------  ----
  432          1  Leftoverture          1976
  435          1  Point of Know Return  1977
  438          1  Monolith              1979
  561          2  Grand Illusion        1977
```

*Question: But albums have songs. ... Should I therefore keep the attribute 'Songs' out of the Album table?*

Yes.  If it's a one to many relationship between `album` and `song`, then store the `album_id` on the `song` table.

Like this:

songs:

```
song
----
id           'PK'
album_id     'FK ref album.id'
song_title
lyrics
```

song

```
id    album_id  song_title         
----  --------  ------------------------
6777       435  Dust In The Wind
6801       438  People of the South Wind
5555       561  Come Sail Away
```

From a row in the `song` table, we can use the value stored in the `album_id` column to find the related `album`.

From a row in the `album` table, we can use the value stored in the `artist_id` column to find the related row in `artist`.

---

These examples are based on the simplistic one-to-many relationships that are described.

It's important that we get these rules for the relationships between the entities into a reasonable representation. We need to know if a relationship is one-to-many or many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read Database Systemsby Connolly & Begg - who will define clearly what makes data relational and how to define entities, and when to normalise data, but yes in answer to your question around whether you should use a foreign key in the songs table to link the artist to the song - remember this table will hold songs which means naturally the artist id would appear multiple times, and so on and so on research entities properly that will help.