# Is it a good idea to use multiple M2M relationships between two entities?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, m2m

We have a situation where we appear to need to use two different M2M relationships between two entities in a database.

The entities are `Users` and `Studies`. Users can *enroll* in studies, but also might be *eligible* for studies.

Therefore, we are considering modelling this with two different tables: `Enrollments` and `Eligibilities`.

With schemas looking like:

- `Studies`:

  - `study_id` PK
- `User`

  - `user_id` PK
- `Enrollments`:

  - `enrollment_id` PK
  - `user_id` FK
  - `study_id` FK
- `Eligibilities`

  - `eligibility_id` PK
  - `user_id` FK
  - `study_id` FK

**My question is: is this a good idea?** I know that this would create two M2M relationships between two entities when it is advised to combine them into one. The issue when combining these relationships into one table is that these relationships are independent. For example, a user might be eligible for a study and not enroll, and a user might enroll in a study but not be eligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modeling multiple many to many relationships between the same entities in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079568/modeling-multiple-many-to-many-relationships-between-the-same-entities-in-a-rela)

Comment: Hi philipxy - thanks for your response. The answer you linked did not answer the question that I had. It is a much more general example that did not clearly guide me in my current situation.

Additionally, the "How to Ask" link describes the steps to "improve your chances of getting an answer". I'm very happy with the answer I received. Therefore, clearly my question was phrased adequately.

Comment: Getting an answer does not imply your question was phrased adequately. Also I didn't say it wasn't phrased adequately. Also you don't quote everything from the link, and unclear & duplicate questions can be closed (have answers blocked). Also your question is a commonly asked one re DB/SQL subtyping/inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, perfectly OK; just pay attention to keys.

> I know that this would create two M2M relationships between two entities when it is advised to combine them into one.

No it is not advised. Simply focus on logic, predicates and constraints, as opposed to jargon (m2m ...).

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- Study STY exists.
--
study {STY}
   PK {STY}
```

```
-- User USR is eligible for study STY.
--
eligibility {USR, STY}
         PK {USR, STY}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user  {USR}
FK2 {STY} REFERENCES study {STY}
```

*If a user enrolled into a study, then that user must be eligible for that study.*

```
-- User USR enrolled in study STY.
--
enrollment {USR, STY}
        PK {USR, STY}

FK {USR, STY} REFERENCES eligibility {USR, STY}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Thanks Damir, I was also looking for such an explanation