# What is the equivalent, in Relational Algebra, of a SQL Table Relationship?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relationship, entity-relationship, relational-algebra

If I understand correctly, the *Relational Algebra* equivalent of a *SQL* `table` is a `relation`.

What is the equivalent term in *Relational Algebra* of a *SQL* `relationship` (*i.e. between two tables*)?

Comment: I don't remember my notes exactly, but I don't think there is one. You have a JOIN in relational algebra, which is an X closed on the sides, but that's an operator and not a concept.

Comment: It should be noted that SQL doesn't really talk about "relationship"s either. SQL has foreign keys that *reference* tables. The "relationship" terminology has come about, I believe, from people mis-applying the term from ERDs and getting confused by the fact that SQL claims to be "relational". People put 1 and 1 together and got cheese, but it seems impossible to stamp it out :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is one.  The concept of related sets isn't part of set theory.  You only have sets and the operators that act upon them.

Comment: I agree: _if_ there's a cross-reference between tables in SQL (to avoid the word "relationship"), then that's tables within a database. As Relational Algebra is usually presented, it only talks about relations, not databases nor persistence nor update thereof. But see the writings of Date and Darwen for a fully worked-out model.

Answer (score 1):

A "relationship" [sic] between two tables or relations is a notion from pseudo-ERM  (Entity-Relationship Model) information modeling methods, products & presentations that call themselves ERM but aren't because they misunderstand, misuse & misrepresent the ERM & RM (Relational Model). It isn't a term from SQL. It corresponds to a FK (foreign key) in the RM.

(In the ERM & RM a "relationship" is an "association" is a "relation" in the sense of a truth-valued function. As represented by a RM "relation" in the sense of a collection of tuples of entities/values that participate together.)

A SQL FK corresponds to what we could reasonably call a foreign superkey in the RM. [Does an empty SQL table have a superkey? Does every SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029100/3404097)

(The ERM & SQL also misunderstand, misuse & misrepresent the RM. [What is the difference between an entity relationship model and a relational model?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27272088/3404097))

A RA (relational algebra) is a system of values & operators on relations & maybe other types. A language whose expressions are essentially nested RA operator calls is often also sloppily called a RA. A relation (value or variable) FK is a set or list of attributes whose subtuple values are constrained to appear elsewhere. A FK constraint says that subtuple values for a given set or list of attributes in a given named relation also appears under given attributes of a second given named relation. (Such a constraint is also sloppily called a FK.) Since a FK constraint is a statement about relation values and not a relation value, it isn't expressible directly in terms of relation values & operators. It could be in a particular RA-style query language that lets you write boolean-valued expressions.

One RM notion of FK as set is that {r, ...} is a FK in R referencing CK {r, ...} in S iff/when `project r, ... (R)` is a restriction of `project r,... (S)`. One notion of FK as list is that (r, ...) is a FK in R referencing (s, ...) in S iff/when {s, ...} is a CK of S and `rename r\s, ... (project r, ... (R))` is a restriction of `project s,... (S)`.

Nevertheless it is straightforward to express constraints while limiting ourselves to relation names & nested RA calls. We express whether a constraint holds on given named relations via a query that has some agreed-upon property iff/when the constraint holds. One such convention is to give a query that returns an empty relation iff/when its named relations satisfy the constraint. The simplest convention is a query that returns a relation with no columns (of which there are two, the one with a tuple & the one without) that has a tuple iff/when the constraint is satisfied.