# Relational Schema to ER Diagram /Cardinalities difference

Tags: database, relational-database

If we have an **ER diagram** and we want to **convert to  a relational schema** we follow a specific procedure (eg Elmashri& Navathe book). 
What is not clear to me is if there is a **difference** when there is a cardinality of **1:1 vs 1:N**. How is this difference represented in the relational schema?

For example in the following figure from Elmashri if we focus on the relation between Department-Project that has a cardinality of 1:N we take the following relational schema. 
If the cardinality was 1:1 would there be a difference?

And to ask more directly: In the following figure, if somebody was giving me only the left part of it with the relational schema, how would I say if the 2 relations (in black and red circle) are 1:1 or 1:N?

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Please clarify posts via edits not comments. PS I don't understand your question. The textbook tells you how to read & map the diagram. Tell us what you think the book says the relevant part of the diagram says & says what to map to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re mapping from ER & pseudo-ER to relational**

That is a Chen style of ER diagram. Diamonds denote relation(ship)s/associations & have corresponding tables/relations. Lines denote participations & have corresponding FKs. Cardinalites are about diamonds ie relation(ship)s/associations ie tables/relations. They tell you certain things about what combinations of entities can participate in a relation(ship)/association.

Your textbook is Fundamentals of Database Systems 7th edition by  Elmashri & Navathe. It follows the above usage & explains how to map X:Y:etc & explains how it mapped your example in particular. That DDL can arise from mapping the ERD to obvious "cross reference"/"relationship" tables then combining them. But your textbook just gives multiple ways to map X:Ys without clearly explaining how the shortcut ways arise from the obvious ways plus combining.

Eg: The table that is the value of query `select Dnum, Pnum from PROJECT` represents the binary relationship "for some Pname & Plocation, department Dnum controls project Pnum"--which is presumably true exactly when "department Dnum controls project Pnum"--which is relationship CONTROLS on a DEPARTMENT & a PROJECT. The ER diagram says that the corresponding binary relation is 1:N in Dnum:Pnum & N:1 in Pnum:Dnum. *Because* CONTROLS has that particular 1 in its cardinality, its obvious table *can* be combined with the PROJECT entity table into table PROJECT. If it were M:N then combining would have certain problems so your text gives a different mapping--but under the previous presumption it still *could* be. And if you did that or just used the obvious mapping then your relational design would be the same for both 1:N & M:N. 1:1 allows yet other combinations.

Different design & diagramming methods have different conventions for cardinalities & mapping to relations. Many so-called ER methods are not really ER in that they are trivially ER--everything is a (possibly associative) entity. All lines involve a 1 or 1-or-0 at one or both ends--because they are about certain implicit binary relationships & tables associated with FKs--like when obvious Chen tables are combined as above. Also there are look-here & look-away cardinalities & other conventions like explicit null FKs. All depends on what textbook/reference/method are you using.

Your DDL diagram "relation" is a FK--wrongly but ubiquitously called a "relationship" by pseudo-ER methods. You are not using "X:Y" meaningfully in the DDL diagram. You are using it more or less how a pseudo-ER diagram would label a FK. But the cardinality is *about* the relation(ship)/association represented by a certain projection of the FK's referencing table.

**Re mapping from relational to ER & pseudo-ER**

If you started from a Chen ER design & used only the obvious mappings then you would have tables 1:1 with entities & relationships & the entity tables would be the ones with no FKs. But your textbook has multiple mapping choices that involve combining ER diagram entity & relationship tables into other tables, in multiple ways, so the tables in the database don't tell you the diagram entities & relationships that they arose from.

Relational designs are more general than Chen ER designs--tables represent relations on 0 or more values. (Every superkey of every base table & query result identifies some entity.) So not all reasonable relational designs correspond to Chen ER designs. Whereas one benefit of the pseudo-ER methods is that they are really recording DDL and not distinguishing between entities & relationships. But if they do arise from entities & relationships that's not recorded in the design. So you can't map from such a relational/pseudo-ER design back to those entities & relationships.

You wouldn't know the cardinality from DDL constraints unless you put them in --which you should, preferably declaratively but otherwise triggers. FKs & CKs (via PKs & UNIQUE NOT NULL) are enough to express Chen cardinality constraints for binary relation(ship)s/associations, but not n-ary. Pseudo-ER methods may or may not address constraints beyond PKs & CKs. And Chen ER designs can have problem constraints that must be addressed through general relational design principles--so really they are only provisional. (And--unnecessary.)

[What is the difference between an entity relationship model and a relational model?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27272088/3404097)